# count(*) type compatibility error with Database.PostgreSQL.Simple?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, postgresql-simple

The error is

```
*** Exception: Incompatible {errSQLType = "int8", errHaskellType = "Int", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
```

It looks like any value returned by `count(*)` in the query must be converted into `Integer` rather than `Int`. If I change those specific variables to type Integer, the queries work.

But this error wasn't being raised on another machine with the same exact code. The first machine was 32 bit and this other one 64-bit. That's the only difference I could discern.

Does anyone have any insight into what is going on?

Comment: have you tried using `Int32` or something?

Comment: I haven't tried Int32, but I think that may work just as well as Integer. I just have not seen this integer type conversion wrinkle documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL count() functions returns a Bigint  type, see

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html

Bigint  are 8 bytes
 see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html

Haskell int is  ~ 2**29 which implies it a 4 byte integer.

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Int.html

Then its normal that PostgreSQL or its API will not do an implicit downwards conversion in precision.

So use a Haskell int64 type or     cast count(*) to integer.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [FromField](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.3.7.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html) module,  postgresql-simple will only do client-side conversions between numerical types when there isn't any possibility of overflow or loss of precision.  Note especially the list of types in the haddocks for the `instance FromField Int`:  "int2, int4, and if compiled as 64-bit code, int8 as well. This library was compiled as 32-bit code."   The latter part of that comment is of course specific to the build that hackage itself performs.

On 32-bit platforms,  `Int` is a 32-bit integer,  and on 64-bit platforms,  `Int` is a 64-bit integer.   If you use `Int32` you'll get the same exception.   You can use `Int64` or the arbitrary-precision `Integer` type to avoid this problem on both kinds of platform.